# Are there spacing mixins in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, mixins, spacing

Bootstrap 4 provides a bunch of spacing classes, which all are using the $spacer SASS-variable.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

Are there any mixins so one could apply these spacings to elements in cases, where one can not - or doesn't want - to modify the html and add the related classes? So it would be possible to have spacing depending on the $spacer value, for elements without the bootstrap-classes,

For Example something like

```
.myClass {
    @include mt-1; //behaves like adding the mt-1 class to the element itself
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a mixin. Why not simply use the $spacer variable on your custom class?

```
.myClass {
    margin-top: $spacer*.25;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/lfGsenoKpF

Comment: Thanks, that would sure do the trick. But I was wondering if there is something a bit more "speaking" in a sense, that it clearly communicates "this should behave like it has this class" in comparison to "yeah, $spacer*.25 looked alright in the browser, so we took it".